# Let $W={W_t:t≥0}$ be a Brownian motion. Find $\mathbb{E}(W_t(W_{t+1} + W_{t+2}))$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Looking at a problem set for an introduction to Brownian motion: I think it's the syntax that's getting me confused, but I'm a bit stumped on the following question (I suspect that knowing what's going on with this one will let the rest fall into place in my mind)...

Anyway, without further ado:

Let $W={W_t:t≥0}$ be a Brownian motion. Find $\mathbb{E}(W_t(W_{t+1} + W_{t+2}))$.

Thanks in advance, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in these sorts of things there's not really much to do except try to exploit the independence of the increments. So here, $W_{t+2}=W_{t}+W_{t+2}-W_{t}$ and $W_{t+1}=W_t+W_{t+1}-W_t$. Thus, we get

$$
\mathbb{E}W_t(W_{t+1}+W_{t+2})=2\mathbb{E} W_t^2+\mathbb{E}W_t(W_{t+2}-W_{t})+\mathbb{E}W_t(W_{t+1}-W_t)
$$
And by independence and Gaussianity, we thus get

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}W_t(W_{t+1}+W_{t+2})&=2\mathbb{E} W_t^2+\mathbb{E}W_t\left(\mathbb{E}(W_{t+2}-W_{t})+\mathbb{E}(W_{t+1}-W_t)\right)\\
&=2t,
\end{align}
since the other terms are $0$.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! New account so my +1 doesn't reflect, but that's cleared a lot up for me - thank you!

Comment: Note that the good rewriting is $W_{t+2}=W_t+(W_{t+2}-W_t)$ rather than what I originally wrote, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Using this same approach, you may prove in general that $E[W_s W_t] = \min(s,t)$.  And if you remember that fact, then you can solve this problem at a single glance.